# Integral of $1/(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What should I substitute to calculate the integral of $1/(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}$? With a being constant. Or is there a better way than substituting for this?

I tried $u=x^2+a^2$ but then I'm left with a $2x$, so that's no good. And then perhaps something with sinus/cosinus/tangens, but I'm a little lost then. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: try $x = a \sinh t$.

Comment: use $$\frac{-2}{a}\frac{d}{da}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}dx = \int \frac{1}{\left(x^{2} + a^{2}\right)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: @Chinny84: [Feynman](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf) would be proud ! :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint:***
$$x=a\tan\theta\implies dx=asec^2\theta d\theta ,\ \ \ x^2+a^2=a^2\sec^2\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

The above substitution is very nice.  In case you were interested in another substitution you can write 
$$
I=\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}
$$
and now let $x=a\sinh \phi, dx=a\cosh \phi d\phi$.  Re-writing the integral we have
$$
I=\int \frac{a\cosh \phi d\phi}{(a^2(\sinh^2 \phi+1))^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{a^2}\int \frac{\cosh \phi d\phi}{\cosh^3 \phi}=\frac{1}{a^2}\int \frac{d\phi}{\cosh^2 \phi}=\frac{1}{a^2}\left( \tanh \phi + C\right).
$$
Note $x=a\sin h \phi$, thus we can write $\phi=sinh^{-1}(x/a)$ and re-write I to obtain
$$
I=\frac{1}{a^2}\left(\tanh\big(sinh^{-1}\frac{x}{a}\big)+C\right)=\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}+C.
$$
I hope this is useful too!